# Algorithm to find the chromatic number of a graph (its not greedy)!!

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I have thought of an algorithm to find the chromatic number of a graph but I don't know whether it's right or not. Could someone confirm this for me?

So it works like this:

Suppose we take the graph with $N$ vertices (say $v_1,v_2,v_3\dots v_n$).

We denote a chromatic number by $x$, which is initialised by $0$ for now and take an empty set $z=\{\}$, which will contain all the nodes that we choose from the graph for finding the chromatic number.

Now basically what we do is, we take the node with highest degree (say $v_m$) and add it to our set $z$ and increment $x$ by $1$.

Now we take the node adjacent to $v_m$ (say $v_l$) and compare it with the nodes present in our set $z$, for checking its adjacencies. If we find any node non-adjacent to the selected node, we give them the same colour, and $x$ remains the same. But if we don't, then we add the element to our set and increment $x$ by $1$. Now suppose we don't find any node, so now our set is $z=\{v_m,v_l\}$ and $x=2$.

please note that if we have multiple nodes connected to the node with the our currently selected node i.e the node of the maximum degree for now  then what we do is we compare their degrees(but not the actual ones)we calculate their degree only by making their connections with the nodes that already exist in our set.we don't take into account their connections with the nodes that are not n the set.

if after comparison also the degree of the adjacent nodes are same , then what we randomly select any node.

Now we take the next node by comparing the degree(degrees are calculated based on the method above) of all the adjacent nodes that are adjacent to our previously selected nodes and in them we select the nodes which have the highest degree or multiple nodes having same degree  we colour them according to the set based method stated above.

We repeat the same process for the other nodes, but the thing to note here is whenever we find a node non-adjacent to given node in the set, we first traverse all the elements that are having the same colour to the element which is non-adjacent to the current element.

if we can't go to any other node in the latter stages of this process then what we do is search for the next node with the highest degree among all the remaining nodes.

For making a record of all the elements which are having the same colour, we are maintaining $z$. For example, $\{\{v_r,v_m\},v_l\}$ where $v_r$ and $v_l$ have the same colour.

Each time we don't find any node non-adjacent to our current node, we add it to our set and increment $x$ by $1$.

After traversing all the nodes, the number of elements in the set $z$ is the chromatic number of the graph.

One thing to note here is whenever we find a node non-adjacent to the current node, we insert it in our set $z$ at the position of the non-adjacent node in the form of nested sets in the set $z$. But firstly we store the current node in the beginning of the nested set, and push back all the nodes available in the nested set. So that next time we compare a node in the set, we first compare the most recent node to save time.

If we find any node which is adjacent to the current node in the nested set, we break our check and move to the other nested sets of the parent set $z$.

Comment: @yash Welcome to MSE. Unfortunately, unless you edit your question to make it more readable by including proper capitalization and punctuation and spacing your text into smaller paragraphs, nobody is going to read it.

Comment: done!@Omnomnomnom

Comment: I mean, the answer is certainly "no, it's not right", because the coloring problem is NP-complete and what you have is not long or novel enough to be a proof that P=NP. The easiest way to prove this would be to find a graph on which it uses too many colors, but maybe you could help us out here by trying to look for that graph first.

Comment: (The algorithm is also under-specified; what if we can't go to any node adjacent to our most recent node, but we still haven't visited all the nodes? Where do we go next?)

Comment: ya what u told may be right!! but i just want a counter example for which my algorithm is not working , I am not saying that i have proved it but i am just eager to find a counter example for which my algorithm fails !!@MishaLavrov

Comment: can u give any example in which we are not able to an adjacent node !!

Comment: while making this algorithm i was imagining that i am creating the graph from scratch,and observing the effect of each and every node on the cromatic number

Comment: The simplest example where we can't keep going to an adjacent node is the [paw graph](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=646). Your instructions say to start in the middle, at the vertex of degree 3; then you go to the highest-degree neighbor (some vertex of degree 2). Then you visit the other vertex on the left. The rightmost vertex of degree 1 remains unvisited, but it's not adjacent to the last vertex.

Comment: ya u are right !! so basically what i think is we should go as per the algorithm, then i any vertices remains uncoloured , then we can repeat the entire algorithm taking that vertex as the new starting vertex but we don't change our set z.@MishaLavrov

Answer (score 4):

A bad example for your algorithm is the graph below:

[image]

This is a modification of the envelope graph used in [Kosowski and Manuszewski, *Classical coloring of graphs*](http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Personal/Andrzej_Lingas/k-m.pdf) as a bad example for a different coloring algorithm.

The first five vertices your algorithm is forced to consider, by starting at the highest-degree vertex and moving to a neighbor with the highest degree at each step, are vertices $1,2,3,4,5$ in the diagram below:

[image]

The set $z$ in your algorithm will be $\{1\}$ with $x=1$, then $\{1, 2\}$ with $x=2$, then $\{\{1,3\},2\}$ with $x=2$, then $\{\{1,3\}, 2, 4\}$ with $x=3$, then $\{\{1,3\}, 2, 4, 5\}$ with $x=4$. It doesn't matter what you do with the remaining vertices; you'll end up with a $4$-coloring.

However, this graph can be colored with $3$ colors, so your algorithm performs sub-optimally here.

Comment: Wow , Dude its awesome !! So if we observe carefully the problem of choice arises in case the degree of nodes are same ,so for overcoming this drawback ,what we can do is basically put a condition like if the degree of nodes are same then we prefer the node which is adjacent to the previous of previous node like in the third step 5,4,3 have the same degree so we prefer 5 as it is adjacent to 1.   Ps:i have used 5,4,3 only for explaining the nodes location .

Comment: What you say ? Can we overcome this drawback of this algorithm in some more efficient or different way ?@Misha Lavrov

Comment: Even if we break ties differently, we can modify the graph so that this order of vertices is used when there are no ties. Add $100$ vertices to the graph that are only adjacent to vertex 1, $90$ vertices that are only adjacent to vertex 2, $80$ vertices adjacent to vertex 3, and now in the third step vertex 3 will have a massively higher degree than vertices 4 or 5.

Comment: So what u think ,how can we optimise our choices of the next node ,as degree can be fluctuated we need some other parameter for choosing the next node@Misha Lavrov

Comment: Well, my belief is that no approach of this type will work. If it did, it would give an incredibly fast graph coloring algorithm and prove that P=NP - and this is not what a revolutionary proof of an incredibly hard open problem looks like.

Comment: One idea that should work here is probably inspite of choosing the vertex with the highest degree in total we can take all the adjacent vertices to a particular vertex and can calculate their degree only on the basis of the vertices that are pre existing in our set z .we can start from the node with the highest degree then can go to the second highest degree vertex ,the for the next vertex choice we will calculate  the degree of the adjacent vertices only on the basis of their adjacencies with the nodes present in our set z

Comment: In this way we will not be able to fluctuate the degree of any vertex

Comment: see don't get me wrong,but you can't say that an algorithm will not work,just because it's not complex enough, sometimes the problems are not complex it is we who make them simple or complex @Misha Lavrov

Comment: if you don't believe it will work then just give a contradictory example, so that i can work out on it ,or just understand that why my algorithm will  not work.but saying just that the algorithm is not complex enough is not right what i think :)@Misha Lavrov

Comment: "Just give a contradictory example" We already went through two iterations of that. You'll just modify your algorithm to something different and keep asking the same question, and I'm not interested in playing whack-a-mole.

Comment: okay this is the last time, if this time we reach a contridiction i will accept that my algorithm will not work @Misha Lavrov